# Optimization makes function return immediately instead of executing

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, optimization, release

I'm working on VS 2010 express and trying to do some file reading and parsing work

my function goes something like this... (I dropped the boring parts)

```
void SomeClass::SomeFunc(char *ALName, std::map<...> *chromList, std::map<...> *chromLine)
{
    ifstream file;
    char tmpBuff[500];
    char tmpBuff2[500];
    char fileName[350];
    char tmp[350];
    char *pch;
    char *pch2;

    .....

    file.open(fileName);

    while ( file.getline( tmpBuff, 500 ) ) 
    {
        ....
        if ( some_condition == 0 )
        {
          pch2 = strtok( NULL, "," );
          pch = strtok( NULL, "," );
          (*chromList)[pch2] = do_some_work( atoi(pch), tmpBuff2 );
          strcpy( tmp, get_chrom_line( tmpBuff2 ) );
          (*chromLine)[pch2] = tmp;
        }
    }

    file.close();

 }
```

When I change to Release with Optimization set to Maximum speed this function is skipped. 
The debugger enters the function and immediately returns.

When i run with Debug setting or Release with the Optimization flag set to disabled, the function runs just fine.

What can be the possible reason for that?
Can I put a preprocessor definition to force "No optimization" on this function while the rest of the code get optimized

Thanks!!
Idan

Comment: I think the boring parts might be important. Since you are reading from a file the compiler has to assume side-effects and may not optimize away the reading.

Comment: Debugging with optimization on is tricky, since the code executed is not necessarily in the same location / order. Also, you can't necessarily rely on watch values showing the real values.

Comment: -->1 The boring parts contains mostly file path concatenation and simple strtok & strcmp calls.
-->2 I'm not trying to debug a Release code but I can see that it does nothing.

Comment: Maybe the compiler thinks that some_condition never equals 0, so it omits the section. Can we take a look at the 'some_condition' part?

Comment: Possible problems: 'some_condition' somehow managed to be deducted to be always nonzero. Or maybe some buffer overflows, and overwrites your pointers. As a result you add elements to your maps, but not those maps which you think you do. The bug might as well be inside the "do_some_work" function, which trashes your stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that the function is actually being skipped and that the debugger isn't simply making it look skipped?

If it really isn't being executed then it's almost certain you have undefined behavior that happens to work how you want it when not optimized and the compiler (probably rightfully) optimizes it into non-working code in optimized mode.

That said I see some questionable items: You call `strtok` with `NULL` (aside - prefer `0` or `nullptr` in C++/C++11) without calling it with a valid pointer. Are you aware that `strtok` is destructive?

Then you use a character pointer to index an array, or presumably (hopefully?) call an overloaded `operator[]` function with a `char*` argument.

Since this is C++, your code will be cleaner, safer, and probably easier to debug if you remove all the C-style parsing and do it with `string` and `find`/`find_first_of`/etc depending on your needs.

Comment: I'll change the strtok manipulation. it was built for a test and stayed like this.
The `operator[]` is not a problem the map key is `std::string` so a implicit cast is made.

Answer (score 5):

You should never try to debug optimized code. The line numbers it shows you will rarely match up with what is actually being executed, and forget about reading local variables. That is why there is a "Debug" and "Release" mode.

However, if you really want to, [try this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to make Visual Studio not optimize that function. You could also put that function in a separate source file and compile it in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm not trying to debug "Release" code but the output of this function is weird. The code is compiled in Release mode (Optimization on) but this function doesn't get executed. Whether I debug it or run the output.exe

Comment: Well, that is interesting. How do you know it isn't getting executed? I guess you could just leave that pragma there so the function never gets optimized.

Comment: The chromList & chromLine maps stay empty... I'll try wrapping it with pragma thanks!